# Why is this Entity Framework LINQ query not resulting in a SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, distinct

Given the entity:

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client
{
    [Column("txtClientId")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [Column("OrganizationName")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
}
```

And the LINQ query:

```
var clients = (from c in database.Clients
                where c.ClientId.Contains(term) || c.ClientName.Contains(term)                
                select c).Distinct();
```

VS Debugging for 'clients' shows the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[txtClientId] AS [txtClientId], 
    [Extent1].[OrganizationName] AS [OrganizationName]
FROM [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[txtClientId] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
    ([Extent1].[OrganizationName] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')
```

Note there is no 'Distinct'. I have searched on this and found a few workarounds like grouping, anonymous types, or doing the distinct in code (ie ToList().Distinct()), but ideally, I would like the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Extent1].[txtClientId] AS [txtClientId], 
    [Extent1].[OrganizationName] AS [OrganizationName]
FROM [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[txtClientId] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
    ([Extent1].[OrganizationName] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')
```

I have tried this with 'ClientId' marked as "[Key]", with no change in behavior.

Why is this not generating the query I expect, and how do I get it to do so?  Since I have workarounds, I'm more interested in understanding what I'm missing here and the best way to get the desired SQL.

Comment: Can the inner query possibly return duplicates, though?

Comment: Do you have multiple clients with the same ClientId?  If not, what good would a distinct do?

Comment: The table is a customer's that is not well managed, and so yes, can have multiple records with the same client id.  This is for an autocomplete textbox, so for our purposes we just want a distinct client id and name.

Comment: I am able to project to a single string and Distinct comes in (ie Select(x=>x.ClientID + c.ClientName).Distinct() works).  I suspect EF thinks the ID is a PK, so is preventing distinct here...

Answer (score 5):

You are calling [`Queryable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456.aspx), which is definately translatable to Sql.

Perhaps LinqToEntities understands your use of Distinct on class `Client` as "referentially different".  Each row in a database is a referentially different instance, even when there is no primary key.

Try projecting the columns you want into an anonymous type (which should use value equality instead of reference equality):

```
select new {c.ClientId, c.ClientName}
```

Comment: This has two issues.  First, the anonymous type can't be passed out of a method, so to return it, you have to cast it back to Client, which causes the SQL to evaluate before I want.  I could probably work around this, but, also it didn't result in the desired SQL. I tried anyway, and it results in SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[txtClientId] AS [txtClientId], 
[Extent1].[OrganizationName] AS [OrganizationName]
FROM [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[txtClientId] LIKE p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') OR ([Extent1].[OrganizationName] LIKE p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with using ".Contains()" in the link query.
Maybe you should try using LINQ chaining instead of Query syntax.
i.e.

```
database
    .Clients
    .Where (client => client.ClientId.Contains(term) || client.ClientName.Contains(term))
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Changing to chained methods has no effect, and removing the contains temporarily does not change the behavior:  still no distinct.